# Prolog: How to check whether each member of the list has a property?

Tags: prolog

In the book "Prolog by Example: How to Learn, Teach and Use it" on page 32:

Check whether all the elements of a list satisfy some property (i.e. a unary predicate).

Logic program:

```
satisfy_property([], _). satisfy_property([X|L], P) :- R=..[P,X],R, satisfy_property(L,P).

beautiful(mary). 
beautiful(anne). 
beautiful(louise).
```

Execution:

```
?-satisfy_property([mary, anne, louise], beautiful). 
Yes
```

**Help modify the program logic:
how can I check each member of the list?**

Comment: What do you mean by "each member". You are recursing across all of the facts with your query.

Comment: It should work like this:

?-satisfy_property([mary, tom, anne, louise], beautiful).
true;
false;
true;
true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work the way you want it?

```
satisfy_property([], _).
satisfy_property([X|L], P) :-
    var(X),
    !,
    write("false "),
    satisfy_property(L,P).
satisfy_property([X|L], P) :-
    R=..[P,X],
    R,
    write("true "),
    satisfy_property(L,P).
satisfy_property([X|L], P) :-
    R=..[P,X],
    not(R),
    write("false "),
    satisfy_property(L,P).

beautiful(mary). 
beautiful(anne). 
beautiful(louise).

?-satisfy_property([mary, tom, TOM, anne, louise], beautiful).
```

This gives me:

```
true false false true true Yes.
```

Comment: @Lucky - Then you'd upvote and accept as the answer. :-)

Comment: of course, but:

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

Most Prolog systems have the [**`maplist/2`** predicate [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2) for that.

So we can define the predicate as:

```
satisfy_property(L, P) :-
    maplist(P, L).
```

or we can implement the predicate ourselves with:

```
satisfy_property([], _).
satisfy_property([H|T], P) :-
    call(P, H),
    satisfy_property(T, P).
```

with [**`call/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/2) an ISO predicate.

Comment: Thanks!

I used predicate "apply", but still it's not a solution:

satisfy_property([], _).
satisfy_property(P, [H|T]) :-
    apply(P, [H]);
    satisfy_property(P, T).

Execution:
?-satisfy_property(beautiful, [mary, TOM, anne, louise]).
true;
true;
true;
false.



Tom is not verified.

Comment: @Lucky: but here you use a "logical or" (`;`) instead of a "logical and" (`,`).

Comment: @Lucky: you also swapped the arguments in the base case, and the recursive case.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment. This information is useful to me.